# Clean OAuth2 token in swift

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, token, revoke-token

In swift I'm calling successfully a callback URL which revoke a token after the user is logout, and right after I call this to enable re-logging

```
func runOauth(){
    self.loadingLabel.isHidden=true
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.oauth2!.logger = OAuth2DebugLogger(.debug)
    
    //code executed when OAuth have finished
    appDelegate.oauth2!.afterAuthorizeOrFail = self.callBackOAuth
    

    var url:URL?
    do{
        //the url for authorizing the user, kronos://oauth/callback" is called after the OAuth finish
        url = try appDelegate.oauth2!.authorizeURL(withRedirect:"kronos://oauth/callback", scope: "auth",params: ["tg":"addon/kronos/main","idx":"login.OAuth","formId":"iOS"])
        do{
            let authorizer = appDelegate.oauth2!.authorizer as! OAuth2Authorizer
            //launch OAuth in embeded view "SafariVC"
            print("Safari embeded")
            safariVC = try authorizer.authorizeSafariEmbedded(from: self,at: url!)
            
        }catch let error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("ERROR authorizing\(error)")
                //self.runOauth()
            }
        }
    }catch let error {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("ERROR creating OAuth URL \(error)")
            //self.runOauth()
        }
    }
}
```

But it re-logging the user automatically when loading logging page, I've tried this:

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
 let authorizer = appDelegate.oauth2!.authorizer as! OAuth2Authorizer
 authorizer.oauth2.forgetTokens()
```

Does someone have a solution?

EDIT:
In fact the first logoff woks well but if I relog I can not sign off anymore and I have that line in the console when it fail

```
[Debug] OAuth2: Did exchange code for access [true] and refresh [true] tokens
```

EDIT2:
I've tried

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.oauth2?.forgetClient()
 appDelegate.oauth2 = OAuth2CodeGrant(settings: OAuthParams  )
 appDelegate.oauth2!.authConfig.authorizeContext = KronosWebsite?.window//KronosWebsite the WKWebview
 runOauth()
```

and I've this in the console

```
[Debug] OAuth2: Forgetting client credentials and removing them from keychain
[Warn!] OAuth2: Failed to delete credentials from keychain: Error Domain=swift.keychain.error Code=-25300 "(null)"
```

EDIT3:
I've tried to empty keychains

```
let secItemClasses = [kSecClassGenericPassword,
                kSecClassInternetPassword,
                kSecClassCertificate,
                kSecClassKey,
                kSecClassIdentity]
for secItemClass in secItemClasses {
      let dictionary = [kSecClass as String:secItemClass]
       SecItemDelete(dictionary as CFDictionary)
}
```

But maybe I need to use  attributes `keychainAccountForClientCredentials` and `keychainAccountForTokens`, so is this possible to access data stored in those keychains?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue, I just had to clean cookies for the SFSafariViewController (I've done that in PHP)